# Python3 PIL (Pillow) draw.pieslice bad arc

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm dawing a simple pieslice with PIL

```
image = Image.new("RGBA", (256, 128), "#DDD")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image, image.mode)
draw.pieslice((0, 0 , 64, 64), 180, 270, fill="white)

del draw

image.save("file.png", "PNG")
```

[image]

As you can see the arc is not perfect. How I can make a perfect arc with PIL?

Comment: It looks pixelated... does it look better if you scale it to a larger number of pixels?

Comment: How much is appropriate?

Comment: I would say until it looks good to you :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw on a larger image, then downscale:

```
N=4
image = Image.new("RGBA", (256*N, 128*N), "#DDD")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image, image.mode)
draw.pieslice((0, 0 , 64*N, 64*N), 180, 270, fill="white")
del draw
image = image.resize((256,128)) # using user3479125's correction
image.save("file2.png", "PNG")
```

Answer (score 3):

Note for unutbu's answer:
Now the resize() returns a resized copy of an image. So it doesn't modify the original. So this should be:

```
N=4
image = Image.new("RGBA", (256*N, 128*N), "#DDD")
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image, image.mode)
draw.pieslice((0, 0 , 64*N, 64*N), 180, 270, fill="white")
del draw
image = image.resize((256,128))
image.save("file2.png", "PNG")
```